# Recover Ubuntu installation

Tags: boot, 13.04, dual-boot, grub2

I'm in a problem..I had Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu ( I had Grub to manage the boot ) and now I reinstalled Windows and now I can't access Ubuntu any more..I don't get an option to boot Ubuntu and no dual boot screen..

I already tried :

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr 
bootrec.exe /FixBoot  
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

and had no luck..Any suggestions?..

Comment: Boot from Ubuntu DVD or stick, open GParted and set the boot flag back to Ubuntu's partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bootrec.exe /FixMbr 
bootrec.exe /FixBoot  
bootrec.exe /RebuildBcd
```

These three commands repair only your Windows boot files.It won't do anything with the grub. After running the above commands, the grub was overwritten by Windows MBR, so you can't able to view grub on startup.

To view grub (with both Windows and Ubuntu option) on startup, you have to run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: Well I wasn't able to view grub from the beginning..That's why I asked here.

Comment: did you try boot-repair?

Comment: It's working right now...I'll wait until it is finished and see the result :D

Comment: yep, go on.Get back after it finished.

Comment: I think it is stuck...It says "Create a BootInfo summary(15)" for the past 10 minutes

Comment: Yeh, get into this [room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/boot-repair-problems-would-be-discussed-here)

Comment: It finally finished :D..Thank you ..It worked like a charm :))

Answer (score 0):

To Restore Ubuntu Try Following Link:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows